# Extract cell addresses from within formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am looking for a way to extract addresses / ranges from a formulae. I have created an example formula below.

```
=SUMIFS(Worksheet_Name!$C$3:$C$20, Worksheet_Name!$A$3:$A$20, "Blue", Worksheet_Name!$B$3:$B$20, "Green")
```

I am trying to get some sort VBA routine which I can pick apart the formulae.

I would like to get the ranges as follows:

```
Worksheet_Name!$C$3:$C$20

Worksheet_Name!$A$3:$A$20

Worksheet_Name!$B$3:$B$20
```

So I can access these separately.

Comment: Take a look at `FORMULATEXT` if you have office 365.

Comment: Have a look at [`DirectPrecedents` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.directprecedents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following, this will take a cell as input, then it will strip out anything outside the brackets and split the remainder of the formula by commas into an array, and then it will display then in a Msgbox, but you can adapt that to your needs:

```
Sub Get_Ranges_In_Formula()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare the worksheet you are working with
Dim rngs As String
Dim arrayofRngs

cellvalue = ws.Range("A1").Formula
'get the formula from the cell

openingParen = InStr(cellvalue, "(")
closingParen = InStrRev(cellvalue, ")")
rngs = Mid(cellvalue, openingParen + 1, closingParen - openingParen - 1)
'strip anything outside the brackets

arrayofRngs = Split(rngs, ",")
'split by comma into array

For i = LBound(arrayofRngs) To UBound(arrayofRngs)
    If InStr(arrayofRngs(i), "!") > 0 Then MsgBox arrayofRngs(i)
Next
End Sub
```

A solution using RegEx to extract cell references from formulas:

```
Sub Get_Ranges_In_Formula()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim xRetList As Object
    Dim xRegEx As Object
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRet As String
    Dim Rg As Range

    Set Rg = ws.Range("A1")
    Application.Volatile
    Set xRegEx = CreateObject("VBSCRIPT.REGEXP")
    With xRegEx
        .Pattern = "('?[a-zA-Z0-9\s\[\]\.]{1,99})?'?!?\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?[0-9]{1,7}(:\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?[0-9]{1,7})?"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
    End With
    Set xRetList = xRegEx.Execute(Rg.Formula)
    If xRetList.Count > 0 Then
        For I = 0 To xRetList.Count - 1
            MsgBox xRetList.Item(I)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep, you've solved it for some formulae like the example sumifs.

Comment: Yep, you've solved it for some formulae like the example sumifs.

However, I will never know what type of formulae I am using this routine on;

For example it could be:

=Sum(A1:A2)+Sum(A3:A4)

which this would not work on. Also, it could be index matches etc. So potentially doing it on splitting of a ", " may not be the solution

Comment: @JamesGTaylor my updated solution should work for both formula examples now,... :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Sub Test()
    Dim e, s As String
    s = MyArguments(Range("A1"))
    For Each e In Split(s, ",")
        If InStr(e, "!") Then Debug.Print Trim(e)
    Next e
End Sub

Function MyArguments(rng As Range) As String
    MyArguments = Split(Split(rng.Formula, "(")(1), ")")(0)
End Function
```